# RewriteRule for multiple robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site with multiple domains and i need a robots.txt for each domain.

For example:

```
example.com will have robots-com.txt
example.se will have robots-org.txt
example.co.uk will have robots-co.uk.txt
```

etc...
And the URL would be example.com/robots.txt

So I wrote this:

```
RewriteRule ^.*example\.(.*)/robots\.txt robots-$1.txt [L]
```

(i thought) that it would take the domain and add it to the end of the robots file.
But it doesn't work.

How should I do, is it possible?

---

I rewrote it like this, still doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP-HOST} ^.*example\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-%1\.txt [L]
```

---

**Working solution:**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*example\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots-%1\.txt [L]
```

Comment: You want to take a look at `RewriteCond %{HTTP-HOST}` and use the %1 backreference in your RewriteRule.

Comment: @JonLin I tried but it didn't work. See above.

Comment: in .htaccess file, the leading slash in a URI is stripped, so the match should be `^robots\.txt$`

Comment: @JonLin I removed it but it still doesn't work...

Comment: sorry, the variable is %{HTTP_HOST} (underscore, not dash)